# Issue with Eclipse content assist is taking too long because of package time out

Tags: eclipse

I am getting long delays with eclipse code content assist because a package that is  included no longer exists.  I have tried numerous things to no avail.   Can anyone help with this issue or recommend how to delete the reference to the bad package.

the package is http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.8.1/R-3.8.1-20160912100321/repository/content.xml

```
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2018-06-22 11:21:27.761 
!MESSAGE Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.8.1/R-3.8.1-20160912100321/repository/content.xml !STACK 0 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ you can disable or remove the not longer available update site. But I don't know what this has to do with content assist. [Make sure your IDE is up to date.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F)

Comment: It doesn't it was bleed trough from another issue.   sorry for the confusion